# ring of idempotents of the integral extension of a ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

For any commutative ring $A$, the set of idempotents of $A$ will be denoted as $E(A)$. This set has a (canonical) ring structure. With addition defined by:
$$e+'f=e(1−f)+f(1−e)$$
where $+$ and $−$ are operation in the ring itself. The multiplication operation is the same as the ring itself.

Suppose now I have a commutative unital ring $A$ and let $B$ be another commutative ring that is an integral extension of $A$. Then clearly $E(B)$ is an over-ring of $E(A)$, but is it clear that $E(B)$ is an integral extension of $E(A)$. Are there easy counter examples for this? Would it help if I assumed that $B$ is a finite integral extension of $A$?

**Edit:** The question above had a trivial answer as Todd pointed out. Now Im curious what happens if I really want $E(B)$ to be a finite integral extension of $E(A)$. Does $B$ being a finite integral extension of $A$ gauarantee that?

Comment: I must not be understanding what you mean. Isn't every element $e \in E(B)$ already an integral element, since it satisfies $e^2 - e = 0$? So that $E(B)$ is automatically integral over $E(A)$ even if $B$ isn't integral over $A$? 

Comment: Besides, the sum of two idempotents does not have to be idempotent. Thus $E(A)$ is not a ring.

Comment: @Todd: You are absolutely right.. the sums just confused me. Consider this question answered

@Martin: In the ring of idempotents the sum is defined by 
$e +' f = e(1-f) + f(1-e)$
where $+$ and $-$ are operation in the ring itself. Multiplication remains the same as the ring itself. So here each element is the additive inverse of itself.

Comment: Jose, you could probably add the definition of $E(A)$ to the body of the question (as opposed to leaving it hidden in the comments) because it is not *that* standard, as far as I know.

Comment: @Mariano: I'm not sure how to define it more clearly. The question's first sentence defines $E(A)$, do you mean the operations that I defined in the comments (I'm on it now)? But you are right, indeed some authors write it as $B(A)$. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every element $e$ of $E(B)$ is already integral since it satisfies $e^2 - e = 0$. (This was effectively in a comment above, but perhaps it's better placed as an answer.)

Comment: Nice, you pwned it!

Answer (score 1):

Take any $B$ such that $E(B)$ is infinite (e.g. $k^\mathbb{N}$, $k$ a field) and write it as a quotient of a domain $A$ (e.g. a polynomial ring over $k$). Then $E(A)=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, so $E(B)$ is not finite over $E(A)$.

Comment: I think the OP is talking about "integral extensions" in the classical sense, where an extension really extends something (meaning, it is injective).

Comment: @darij grinberg: good point, but in my example $A$ injects into $A\times B$.